# Unable To Repeatedly Get TKinter Window Dimensions

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently I tried creating the function in which all items on a TKinter GUI will resize themselves to fit the screen, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I did try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("710x300")

def dimloop():
    root.update()
    screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    print(root.winfo_screenwidth())
    button.config(width=round(screenwidth/7.1))
    root.after(10, dimloop)

button = Button(root, text = 'Hello', width=100)
button.place(x=0, y=0)

dimloop()
root.mainloop()
```

But That Did Not Work. Does Anyone Know Any Way To Do This?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "That Did Not Work"? What was the problem?

Comment: After Testing It By Printing The Screen Width Variable, It Kept Printing 2560 Over And Over.

Comment: Maybe because your screen width is 2560 pixels and doesn’t change?

Comment: No, I Can Keep Changing Its Size And It Would Still Stay The Same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `screenwidth` function returns the width of the physical screen. That's not going to change.

If you want the width of the root window you should use `root.winfo_width()`. There's no point in doing this in a loop, you can get the width of the screen and then set the window width and height using the `geometry` method to force it to be a particular size.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and solved my problem.

Although I could just lock the dimensions, I want the user to be able to resize the window.

Thanks!

+1, Accepted.